# How to docker compose scale with a set of containers that depend on each other?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

Within my `docker-compose.yml` I have a service A that has service B and C as clients. I'd say these three could all be grouped to emulate one "system" for the purpose of my project. If I wanted to emulate another "system" for testing purposes I would have to append three additional services named differently with the correct network routing ect since B and C need the service name of A for their build scripts.

```
  A:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true""
  B_client:
    working_dir: /emulator
    command: bash -c "./build/app A 1000"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - A  
  C_client:
    command: bash -c "./build/app A 1000"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - A
```

I was looking into how docker compose can use `scale` to run a number of containers for a service which would be wonderful for my situation if these apps (A B and C) all ran in the same container. But since they cannot and they all need their own interactive terminals I am curious if anyone has delt with this type of issue or if the general answer is to move away from docker-compose for this type of configuration.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, Docker is not suitable for this, as you'll have to write a lot of wrappers around the containers with your own logic. You'll need container orchestration like K8s or Swarm or something...

Answer (score 0):

Scaling isn't suited for running parallel systems. It's more suited for running more instances of the same service in a single system. You'd do that to increase the processing power of that single service.

If you want to run multiple separate systems based on the same docker-compose file, compose has the 'project' concept.

Let's imagine you have a system with three containers: a frontend, a backend and a database. I've made this simple compose file to illustrate:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - ${PORT:-80}:80
  backend:
    image: alpine
    command: tail -f /dev/null
  database:
    image: alpine
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

You can run the default version of this using

```
docker compose -p prod up -d
```

If you also want to run a test system where the frontend is mapped to port 8080, you can create an environment file containing

```
PORT=8080
```

Let's call it `.env.test`.
Then you can spin up a test system using

```
docker compose -p test --env-file .env.test up -d
```

Now you have 2 separate systems running with 3 containers in each. A production system listening on port 80 and a test system listening on port 8080.

They also each have a bridge network, so they can't interfere with each other.

Comment: Thank you! Gotcha I did not realize that about scale. So your example would be two totally separate network spaces. Project 1 cannot reach project 2? There are some common services that the multiple systems I explained would need. In my example container B and C talk to A... and A talks to a backend container so I am looking for a way where I can create another system (A_2, B_2, C_2) and have A_2 also talk to the same backend. But just in a less hard coded way if its possible? Willing to try new technologies.